# Embedding only a JSON object to website, and let client handle the processing

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I've had in idea the other day. For example, instead of using a lot of `<?php ?>` and embedding the info into the html server-side, could we just embed a single JSON string into the HTML with `<?php ?>` and have nothing else, and then let the client process the embedding, with Angular for example?

I've noticed Instagram's website does a similar thing with React:

[image]

Pros:

- Cleaner HTML Code
- Making a barrier between the view and the controller/model (having a php file for processing, a Controller/Model, and handle the View client side with JavaScript and a framework, for ex. Angular or React)
- Reduced server load

Cons:

- More load on client

Any more pros or cons to this?

Comment: So basically you're making an api server and attaching a javascript frontend to it?

Comment: Pretty much. So a Controller would pull data from a Model, format a JSON and embed it into the HTML and send it to the client, and the then client parses the JSON and handles filling out the data into the various places on the website.

Comment: i don't think there should be too much cons about this , just take care of sensitive informations such as secret codes or password for users which only system needs and have nothing to do with the users.  i too have used same kind of functionality and it works great and it's not much of load to the client it works very smooth, just take of sensitive information.

Comment: Sensitive information should be thrown around with HTTP POST I assume.